# How to zoom a powerpoint file with c#?

Tags: c#, interop, zooming, powerpoint

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint library to open and view a PowerPoint file. I'm opening the file as an SlideShow without problems. The code to open the file is the following:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application _pptApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation _ppt;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations _pptPresentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow _pptSlideShowWindow;

private void Open(string fileName)
{
      _pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
      _pptPresentations = _pptApp.Presentations;
      //fileName represents the full path of the file
      _ppt = _pptPresentations.Open(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                     Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
      _ppt.SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;    
      _ppt.SlideShowSettings.ShowType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeSpeaker;             
      _pptSlideShowWindow = _ppt.SlideShowSettings.Run();
}
```

The code above works fine. With the `_pptSlideShowWindow` I can do some operations, like go to next slide `_pptSlideShowWindow.View.Next();` or go to previous slide `_pptSlideShowWindow.View.Previous();`.
I would like to Zoom in and zoom out the presentations while it is on SlideShow. I've been looking around and I haven't seen any solution that works for me. The SlideShowView has a Zoom property but it's read only:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowview.zoom.aspx

I've tried not to open as SlideShow but the result is not good, as I haven't managed to open the file in reading mode programatically.

I'm a bit lost with this. Any help with this will be really appreciated.

Regards,
Pau